# Vulkan memory alignment requirements

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vulkan

I'm implementing a naive memory manager for Vulkan device memory, and would like to make sure that I understand the alignment requirements for memory and how to satisfy them.

So, assuming that I've allocated a 'pool' of memory using vkAllocateMemory and wish to sub-allocate blocks of memory in this pool to individual resources (based on a VkMemoryRequirements struct), will the following pseudocode be able to allocate a section of this memory with the correct size and alignment requirements?

- Request memory with RequiredSize and RequiredAlignment
- Iterate over blocks in the pool looking for one that is free and has size > RequiredSize
- If the offset in memory of the current block is NOT divisible by RequiredAlignment, figure out the difference between the alignment and the remainder
- If the size of the current block minus the difference is less than RequiredSize, skip to the next block in the pool
- If the difference is more than 0, insert a padding block with size equal to the difference, and adjust the current unallocated block size and offset
- Allocate RequiredSize bytes from the start of the current unallocated block (now aligned), adjust the Size and Offset of the unallocated block  accordingly
- Return vkDeviceMemory handle (of pool), size and offset (of new allocated block)
- If we reach the end of the block list instead, this pool cannot allocate the memory

In other words, do we just need to make sure that Offset is a multiple of RequiredAlignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In other words, do we just need to make sure that Offset is a multiple of RequiredAlignment?

for alignment that is nearly sufficient.

in [vkBindbufferMemory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkBindBufferMemory) one of the *valid usage* requirements is:

> `memoryOffset` **must** be an integer multiple of the `alignment` member of the `VkMemoryRequirements` structure returned from a call to `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements` with `buffer`

and there is a parallel statement in the *valid usage* requirements of [vkBindImageMemory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkBindImageMemory):

> `memoryOffset` **must** be an integer multiple of the `alignment` member of the `VkMemoryRequirements` structure returned from a call to `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` with `image`

If the previous block contains a non-linear resource while the current one is linear or vice versa then the alignment requirement is the max of the VkMemoryRequirements.alignment and the device's bufferImageGranularity. This also needs to be check for the end of the memory block.

**However** you also need to take into account that the memory type of the pool must be set in the `memoryTypeBits` flags of `VkMemoryRequirements` .

Comment: Unfortunately there is also **bufferImageGranularity** that needs to be accounted for: "bufferImageGranularity is the granularity, in bytes, at which buffer or linear image resources, and optimal image resources can be bound to adjacent offsets in the same VkDeviceMemory object without aliasing." More on it [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#resources-bufferimagegranularity).

Comment: @Ekzuzy OK, so help me out here. Firstly, what are the implications of aliasing? Secondly, the link implies bufferImageGranularity is related to linear vs non-linear resources within a single VkDeviceMemory? Does that mean the allocation strategy should use separate pools for linear and non-linear resources?

Comment: @ScottOliver it means that if the previous block is allocated to a non-linear resource while the current resource being allocated is linear you need to increase the alignment requirement to bufferImageGranularity. If the following block is non linear then you need to ensure that a there is enough space to align the end of the block to bufferImageGranularity.

Comment: I didn't dig too much into aliasing so I won't be off much help here. I see 3 options: as you wrote, use separate memory objects for optimal images and buffers/linear images; align to the requirement when necessary (track the type of resource bound to a given part of memory); always align to this requirement (whether there are different types of resources in neighbour blocks of memory or not).