# How to create objects in C++ with dynamic alignment requirements?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17

What is the correct way in C++ to allocate and use a buffer with dynamically-specified alignment? The use case that I had in mind was Vulkan dynamic uniform buffers (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45458918/9723177) which discusses the required process in the abstract), for which a constraint on alignment is given via the `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` property on `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits`, which is not known at compile time.

I initially thought I might be able to use `operator new(std::align_val_t)` doing something like

```
Foo* buffer = new(std::align_val_t{alignment}) Foo[n];
```

but that doesn't compile (at least on MSVC).

I've also watched Timur Doumler's CppCon presentation "[Type punning in modern C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc)" which notes that using `reinterpret_cast` on the result of something like `std::aligned_alloc` leads to undefined behaviour.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
std::size_t n = getNumberOfElements(); // possibly not known at compile time
std::size_t alignment = getRequiredAlignment(); // not known at compile time

makeSureMultiplicationDoesNotOverflow(sizeof(Foo), n); // details irrelevant

void* storage = std::aligned_alloc(sizeof(Foo) * n, alignment); // _aligned_malloc on MSVC
if (!storage) { std::terminate(); }
Foo* buffer = new(storage) Foo[n];

// do stuff with buffer

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) { buffer[i].~Foo(); }
std::free(storage); // _aligned_free on MSVC
```

Have I missed something here that's going to cause undefined behaviour?

EDIT: I noticed that the above does not apply the alignment to any objects other than the first one, so that's definitely an oops...

(Obviously in a real application this should be encapsulated into a class to provide RAII, but leaving that out for now so as not to bloat the example code.)

Comment: Only thing I see is not checking return for `storage == nullptr`.

Comment: Note that, at least based on my understanding, `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` in Vulkan is concerned with the alignment of you uniform buffer *on the GPU*. So `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` is only about how you allocate uniform buffers from a larger buffer resource, which only concerns computation of offset on integers of type `VkDeviceSize`. The alignment of the source data on the CPU-side should not be affected by it!?

Comment: Afaik `sizeof(Foo[n])` will be a compile-time constant (see http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#5.sentence-2), so it can't actually account for a dynamic value of `n`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof - good point, serves me right for translating the example from a local code where I had constants there. I'll fix this and the error check because those are not really the things I'm interested in for this question.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - yes, this is confusing me a bit. I *thought* the requirement was GPU-side, but this [example by Sascha Willems](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/dynamicuniformbuffer) uses the alignment for the host-side data as well. Nevertheless even if it is not necessary for Vulkan, I'd still be interested in how to do it from a purely theoretical persepctive.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - also for the Vulkan example I'd presumably have to actually space the objects in the array out with the alignment anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
auto storage = static_cast<Foo*>(std::aligned_alloc(n * sizeof(Foo), alignment));
std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(storage, n);
auto ptr = std::launder(storage);

// use ptr to refer to Foo objects

std::destroy_n(storage, n);
free(storage);
```

Casting a pointer returned by `std::aligned_alloc` to `Foo*` is not undefined behavior. It would be UB if you tried to dereference it right after `std::aligned_alloc` before `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` created `Foo` objects.

**Edit.**

The code above is technically undefined behavior. But it seems that in C++ there is no 100% standard-conforming way to do such an allocation without UB. From the practical point to view this code is reliable and safe. `std::launder(storage)` should probably be used to access `Foo` objects through `storage` pointer.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451770/treating-memory-returned-by-operator-newsizeoft-n-as-an-array) for details and discussions.

Comment: Good point about the VLA, this was a silly error I introduced when rearranging code from my local environment to the SO website.

Comment: @antispinwards, that's what I'm thinking about now. `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` constructs objects using placement new in `storage`.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Is it definitely allowed for `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` to work here, given that pointer arithmetic is not defined outside of arrays? I guess I would also need to ensure the alignment of all subsequent objects in the array as well, not just the first one (to be fair, my question completely missed that!)

Comment: I believe this is indeed technically UB due to the fact that `std::aligned_alloc` is a C library function and does not create an array object. Thus, performing pointer arithmetic on the result (which [`std::uninitialized_default_construct_n`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/specialized.algorithms#uninitialized.construct.default) does) would currently be UB via [\[expr.add\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4)…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, and why should `std::aligned_alloc` create an array object? It allocates storage, you construct objects in that storage. I'm not sure however that `storage` can be used to access these objects without `std::launder`ing first. Also, `uninitialized_default_construct_n` constructs objects "as if", not "with". I guess you deleted comment was correct.

Comment: @Evg it does not create an array object, which is precisely the point. Since there is no array of `Foo*` located at the location the `void*` it returns points to, the pointer arithmetic that `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` performs to construct the objects will invoke undefined behavior…

Comment: @Evg I deleted my comment because looking up the actual definition of `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` revealed to me that, contrary to what I had assumed, it is not specified to simply be creating an array of objects in a given storage. It is rather specified as merely equivalent to looping over the input iterator and constructing objects via placement new (which is a pity): https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/specialized.algorithms#uninitialized.construct.default

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, and why is pointer arithmetic not defined? The standard in [[expr.add](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2)] mentions "possibly-hypothetical". Maybe this is exactly what "possibly-hypothetical" means?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, related unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018409/is-pointer-arithmetic-on-allocated-storage-ub).

Comment: @Evg, the thing about "possibly-hypothetical" array elements has to do with the wording that is in place to make pointers that point one past the last element of an array well-defined. It, unfortunately, does not make pointer arithmetic on arbitrary pointers that don't point to objects well-defined…

Comment: @Evg see [\[basic.compound\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3): *"For purposes of pointer arithmetic and comparison ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past the end of the last element of an array `x` of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical element `x[n]`."*

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, then how would one use `std::get_temporary_buffer` (deprecated, but it doesn't matter)? See [the example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) at cppreference. If pointer arithmetic on uninitialized storage is UB, then this example is broken.

Comment: @Evg I believe this example is technically fine due to the use of (the also deprecated) [`std::raw_storage_iterator`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/storage.iterator) instead of plain pointer arithmetic…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, the standard for `uninitialized_default_construct_n` reads: "Effects: Equivalent to: ..." Does it mean "implemented exactly as"? Can it be interpreted like having something like `std::raw_storage_iterator` to do the job, too? Or maybe it is a wording defect in the standard?

Comment: @Evg my understanding is that that doesn't mean "implemented exactly as" but means that its observable behavior will be indistinguishable from the observable behavior of the code it's equivalent to. For cases where its equivalent code would invoke UB, there is no requirement that it somehow magically won't invoke UB. The story would be different if it were specified not as equivalent to some piece of code but literally as "constructs an array of N objects of type `iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type` in the storage location". But, unfortunately, it isn't. I might be wrong ofc course…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, [another example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill). Now without `std::raw_storage_iterator`. [[uninitialized_­fill](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/uninitialized.fill)] reads: "Effects: As if by:", but [[uninitialized_­default_­construct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/uninitialized.construct.default)] reads "Effects: Equivalent to:". What is the logic behind this difference? The code is almost the same.

Comment: @Evg I belive that this example is does indeed technically invoke undefined behavior for the reasons laid out above. I don't know of a specific difference between "Equivalent to" and "As if by". The specification talks about "Equivalent to" in [\[structure.specifications\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/library#structure.specifications-4). Unfortuantely, I can't seem to find a similar definition for "As if by". I can only assume it means either literally "implemented as" or the same as "Equivalent to"…

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer with a better alternative, but I just want to add that your code has undefined behavior.

The array form of `new`, even the placement-new form that you are using, is allowed to use an unspecified amount of memory from your allocation to store metadata for the runtime (e.g. the size of the allocation for `delete[]` to know how many elements it needs to destroy).

Therefore you have no way of guaranteeing that the allocated memory size is sufficient or that the actual pointer to the array returned by the placement-new is properly aligned.

As far as I can tell from the current draft this seems to change in C++20, making this particular use of the array placement-new well-behaved, but it is not required to be so in C++17 or earlier.