# Constructing array of objects in uninitialized memory

Tags: c++, malloc, language-lawyer, c++17

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139743/how-to-allocate-memory-in-c-with-dynamic-alignment-requirements).

Suppose we want to manually allocate memory and put `n` objects of type `Foo` into it. I suggested the following code:

```
Foo* storage = static_cast<Foo*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(Foo)));
std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(storage, n);

// ...

std::destroy_n(storage, n);
std::free(storage);
```

This code has raised the question whether it has undefined behavior or not.

The standard draft on `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` [reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/uninitialized.construct.default#3):

> ```
> template<class It, class Size>
> It uninitialized_default_construct_n(It first, Size n);
> ```
>
> Effects: Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> for (; n > 0; (void)++first, --n)
>     ::new (voidify(*first)) typename iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
> return first;
> ```

`storage` does not point to an array, so by [[expr.add]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2) pointer arithmetic on `storage` is UB, and invocation of `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` should be UB, too.

We also have `std::uninitialized_­fill_n` function with almost the [same definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/uninitialized.fill#2). Cppreference gives the [following example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill) for it:

```
std::string* p;
std::size_t sz;
std::tie(p, sz) = std::get_temporary_buffer<std::string>(4);
std::uninitialized_fill(p, p+sz, "Example");
```

[`std::get_temporary_buffer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) returns a pointer to uninitialized memory, like `std::malloc` above, and it seems that we have the same problem in this piece of code.

---

Main question: is the code at the beginning of this question correct?

*If yes*. Do we need to `std::launder` `storage` pointer:

```
auto ptr = std::launder(storage);
consume(ptr[0]);   // or: consume(storage[0]); ?
```

*If no*. Is the reasoning above correct? What about cppreference example? Is `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` limited to the case when `storage` points to an existing array of `Foo` objects?

Comment: There is a good talk at cppcon2019 that goes over just this.  The start of that section is at: https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=881.  Basically, you are SOL since you don't have an array you can't do pointer arithmetic.

Comment: But what about `std::launder`? Do we need it to use `storage`?

Comment: AFAIK it's still illegal after index `0` since you never new'ed an array so index `1` is the past the end index and can't be used.